# What is the highchart pie data structure

Tags: highcharts

I have create a HighCharts Pie as follows :
This a parts of my source:

```
series: [{
                name: 'Temps d\'arrêt',
                type: 'pie',
                data: getTempsDArretSeries(data2),
                center: [35, 0],
                size: 100,
                showInLegend: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
                ,tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' min '+'<br><b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>',
                }
                ,title: {
                    text: 'Temps d\'arrêt'
                },
            }]
```

My function getTempsDArretSeries(data2) is :

```
function getTempsDArretSeries(data){
    var array = new Array();
    var duree = 0;
    var memProduit = 0;
    $(data).each(function(){
        if(memProduit!=0){
            if(memProduit != parseInt(this.efcode)){
                array.push(duree); 
                memProduit = parseInt(this.efcode);
                duree = parseInt(this.efdur);
            }else{
                duree += parseInt(this.efdur);
            }
        }else{
            duree += parseInt(this.efdur);
            memProduit = parseInt(this.efcode);
        }
    })
    array.push(duree); 
    return array;
}
```

I have the result as follows on my chart : 
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3er3D.png)

It is possible to put something like :

```
        name: memProduit,
        y: duree,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
```

for all lines.

Thanks,
Regards,

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/briciou62500/0cLwx279/

I need to write different names on all parts of pie chart.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/863bvny2/

Comment: great it works.

By cons can we change the colors of the graph?

Comment: Yes, you can. Use the keys feature to do it. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.keys

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lz5pke6q/

Comment: Great, thank you very much. ;)